# How many Mythos cards can be played during the investigator's turns?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

I am wondering how playing Mythos cards works. I read that the Keeper can play 1 Mythos card in the investigators' turn. Does that mean:

1) when playing against 4 investigators, the Keeper can play 4 Mythos cards (one card each per single investigator's turn) before his turn comes,

*or*

2) the Keeper can play only 1 Mythos card per a complete turn cycle of all investigators (i.e. the Keeper can play 1 Mythos card before his turn comes)?

Answer (score 8):

**The keeper can play one Mythos card per investigator's turn.**

From the [rules](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/MansionsOfMadnessLoRes.pdf), bottom of the first column on page 16:

> The keeper may play a 
>   maximum of one Mythos card per investigator turn and may 
>   never play Mythos cards during the keeper’s own turn.

Each player/investigator has his own turn each round.  Playing against 4 investigators, the keeper could play a maximum of 4 Mythos cards a round.

From pg. 6

> **Playing the Game**
>
> Mansions of Madness is played over a number of game rounds. 
>   During each round, each player resolves his turn (starting with 
>   the investigators)